# Why doesn't YACC generate shift-reduce conflict?

Tags: c, parsing, bison, yacc, shift-reduce-conflict

Trying to understand shift-reduce conflicts and fix them.

I have following YACC code, for which I was expecting shift-reduce conflict but Bison doesn't generate any such warnings

```
%%

lang_cons: /* empty */
         | declaraion // SEMI_COLON
         | func
    ;

declaraion : keyword ID
    ; 

func : keyword ID SEMI_COLON
    ; 

keyword : INT
    | FLOAT
    ;

%%
```

But if I uncomment SEMI_COLON in 2nd rule (i.e,  `| declaraion SEMI_COLON` ), I get shift-reduce conflict. I was expecting reduce-reduce conflict in this case. Please help me understand this mess!

PS: Consider input,

```
    1) int varName
    2) int func;
```

Comment: Can you indicate which shift you were expecting to conflict with which reduce, and which two reduces you were expecting to conflict?

Comment: When SEMI_COLON is the look-ahead token, the stack will be having (keyword and ID) which are sufficient to reduce with the rule "declaration" or "func"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give bison the `-v` command line flag, it will produce an `.output` file containing the generated state machine, which will probably help you see what is going on.

Note that bison actually parses the augmented grammar, which consists of your grammar with the additional rule

```
start': start END
```

where `END` is a special token whose code is 0, indicating the end of input, and `start` is whatever your grammar uses as a start symbol. (That ensures that the bison parser will not silently ignore garbage at the end of an otherwise valid input.)

That makes your original grammar unambiguous; after `varName` is seen, the lookahead will be either `END`, in which case `declaration` is reduced, or `';'`, which will be shifted (followed by a reduction of `func` when the following `END` is seen).

In your second grammar, the conflict involves the choice between reducing `declaration` or shifting the semicolon. If the semicolon were part of `declaration`, then you would see a reduce/reduce conflict.

Comment: But I saw the *.output file, there is no $end for every rule. The $end is present with only  ( $accept: lang_cons $end).

Comment: @VijaymahanteshSattigeri: No one said that the augmented grammar adds a token to the end of every rule! It adds exactly one rule, as I said. But adding that rule allows the END token to percolate through the lookaheads, resolving what would otherwise be conflicts. Look at the state machine. (You can use `--report=all` to also see all computed lookaheads; read that output together with a good description of the lookahead algorithm, for example in the dragon book.)